# strcat into char[]

Tags: c++, string, string-formatting, c-strings, strcat

I am using argp in a program and it uses a globally defined char doc[] to display information about the program.

Apart from program information, I want to add a GPL notice to this doc.

The GPL notice is defined as a const char * ( but I wouldn't mind changing this) as it is used in a few other places.

Initially I tried this:

```
static char doc[] = strcat("basic program info", GPLNOTICE);
```

But this gives:

```
error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘doc’
```

Then I tried converting to strings:

```
static char doc[] = (string("basic program info") + string(GPLNOTICE)).c_str()
```

But that gives the same error

Then I thought maybe making doc a char * would also work

```
static char *doc = strcat("basic program info", GPLINFO)
```

...but this crashes with segmentation fault

I tried converting the GPL Notice to a macro definition but couldn't really do anything with that

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this line crashes:

```
strcat("basic program info", GPLINFO)
```

is because it tries to modify the constant string literal that is stored in read-only memory, which produces ***undefined behavior***. The correct usage of [`strcat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) could look like this instead:

```
static char buf[1024];
strcpy(buf, "basic program info");
strcat(buf, GPLNOTICE);
```

But since you are programming in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you should prefer using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of C-style strings:

```
std::string doc("basic program info");
doc += GPLNOTICE;
```

Also note that it is good practice to read the documentation of functions like these before you use them :)

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: Heh, I just noticed that I'm missing `;` there :D And don't forget to `#include <string>` :)

Comment: had done both of them....does it make any difference that i made both the statements global